# How to troubleshoot a florescent light.

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

I'd like to know if there is a way to troubleshoot a fixture with T8 or T12 working on a ballast that stopped working, if the problem is in the ballast or the bulbs, without having to buy new bulbs to try them.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes if they don't light and the ends of the bulbs are black you just found 1 answer the bulb is bad. If you replace the bulb and still have trouble your problem is the ballast, electronic ballast die when overloaded. I almost left a sarcastic note at the end of this but will explain. After just changing 3 ballast in very high end fixtures that the owner was two cheap to change lamps. The cost of new fixtures almost 700.00 plus install. I purchased 3 cheap fixtures and pulled the ballast cost just under 110. For the same ballast. I made 400.00 to replace them. Not bad for a few hours work, If he changed the lamps would have cost less than 35 at Home Depot

Comment: The ends of the lamps being black is in no way an indication that the lamp is burned out. Old, yes. On it's way out, yes. But certainly dead, no.

Comment: Being black and flickering or not starting is the leading cause in electronic ballast failure in my experience having starting trouble change the lamp or you will be changing the ballast

Comment: But you said if the ends are black the lamp is bad. First sentence. This is simply not so.

Comment: I said if they don't light AND the ends are black. I have replaced many ballast that had black lamps they may light in a new ballast but will cause another ballast failure I have replaced many hundreds of ballast since the elimination of Mag ballast because of their fire danger.

Answer (score 1):

Thing is, if you replace a ballast it is always best practice to replace the lamps as well.

With older magnetic T-12 ballasts the lamps will go out in pairs, even if one lamp is still good, so troubleshooting can be annoying.

With T-8 electronic ballasts lamps go out individually. If all the lamps go out at the same time, or are even just all out, it is a very good indication that the ballast has failed, although not 100% certain. In my experience it's pretty close though.

Bottom line, you should replace fluorescent lamps with age as well, and even replace all instead of just those that are burned out. Fluorescent lamps loose a good bit of their brightness over time, something like 20-30% within a few thousand hours. This is why when you replace all the lamps in a fixture it seems like a new fixture.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes

How much do you know about electricity?

First off, get the data sheet for the ballast you want to troubleshoot. You will have to test for voltage between the pins on the ends of the lamps and then from one end to the other to see if it matches the rating of the ballast. If it is an electronic ballast it will be more complicated than an old transformer ballast.

After researching this you will probably decide it is easier to just go to the box store and buy a couple lamps for less than $10 and install them. If the ballast doesn't light brand new lamps, it is broke and needs to be replaced.

Good luck!

Comment: Because disposal of tubes isn't always easy (and neither is storage), avoiding ending up with extra tubes lying around seems reasonable.